# java - counting words by hashmap from xml

Tags: java, hashmap

I have program which shows some values from xmls for example to show top ten tags
from xml

```
<row Id="6" TagName="frames" Count="513" ExcerptPostId="5390" WikiPostId="5389" />
```

I have this

```
Map<String, Integer> tagMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Dataset<String> tagData = spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml").textFile(tagsFile).cache();
List<String> tags = tagData.collectAsList();
    for (String t : tags.subList(2, tags.size() - 1)) {

        if (t.contains("ExcerptPostId")) {
            tagMap.put(t.substring(t.indexOf("TagName") + 9, t.indexOf("Count") - 2),
                    Integer.parseInt(t.substring(t.indexOf("Count") + 7, t.indexOf("ExcerptPostId") - 2)));
        } else {
            tagMap.put(t.substring(t.indexOf("TagName") + 9, t.indexOf("Count") - 2),
                    Integer.parseInt(t.substring(t.indexOf("Count") + 7, t.indexOf("/>") - 2)));
        }

    }
tagMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())).limit(10)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which shows two values from file for each record and is pretty easy.
Now I want to count most popular words from body of xml like this

```
  <row Id="172" Body="this text;" " />
```

but I have no idea how to extract single words from this and count.

Comment: If the text is always in the "Body" tag, you might be able to write a regex. A better approach would be to use an XML parsing library. However, word counting is not necessarily easy. Should "girl" and "girls" and "girl's" be one, two, or three words? Usually it is one, but that requires stemming.

Comment: It may be a 3 words, just to count exactly the same expression.